# multiple columns per day with fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show a scheduling plan for a couple of seminar-rooms, each of them in a seperate column, within a fullcalendar day view. So it schould look like a current fullcalendar week view but for every single day.

Is there an obvious solution for this?
And if not, where in the source should i start, what to go for, what to avoid? 
Some suggestions would be nice.

Thanks
Emanuel

Comment: I got it myself:

I just took the agenda-week-view with a modified agenda prototype that prints seminar-room names instead of day identifiers and i add a day-offset to the events so they get into the right columns.

As i just need this one as standalone view, all i've got to do is changing some view properties, like hiding the all-day-pannel and voila.

Its quite a hack ...

Comment: Could you please share your code so it helps others in the same boat?

Answer (score 3):

I've modified the original fullcalendar to handle "resources".. The goal was about the same as Emanuel described.

It's not the best, but might be a good starting point. For now it has bugs and unfinished code, but you can try it out:

http://www.pano360.hu/resourcecalendar/

Comment: Very Interesting. I am trying to achieve something like extscheduler and have posted a few ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269117/integrating-jquery-fullcalendar-with-a-jquery-gannt-chart Please keep us updated if you continue to develop your calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I just published my solution at https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns. It is pretty basic for now but should let you do exactly what you asked. In fact, the implementation of my solution behind the scenes is like a week view, but for a single day. Feature requests are welcome.

Comment: Sir, your are amazing. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: Thanks! Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say submit a [feature request](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/) to the plugin developer as something like this would likely require some significant modification to the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Emanuel Schwarz, how do you have reached your result?
I've tried to develop a system for booking multiple resources, this is the scheme that i've in mind:

### | M 1 | T 2 | W 3 | T 4 | F 5 |

### resource 1   |     |////booked////// //////|

### resource 2   |     |/booked/// |     |     |

### resource 3   |//booked///|     |     |     |

### resource 4   |     |     |/////booked /////|

Now my problem is: I've succesfully modified the month and agenda views with four weeks, but my problem it's that when I select a day more of the first week (also if already has and event) they show all in first week!
You've sayed:

I just took the agenda-week-view with a modified agenda prototype that prints seminar-room names instead of day identifiers 
---- How do you write multiple seminars rooms rows with that title?

and i add a day-offset to the events so they get into the right columns.
---- OK, just what I need to hear :-) ! How do you get this result? Is in a month?

As i just need this one as standalone view, all i've got to do is changing some view properties, like hiding the all-day-pannel and voila. 
----You've hided agenda view with minTime to 0 and maxTime to 0, right?

Its quite a hack ...
Yes, I'ts a pity, but I want to develop this extension for the program, because it will be more productive if he will display a series of resources in a month view like agendaWeek view do (so all day events with no hour display).