# Adding a Resource View/Gannt chart to jQuery Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using [jQuery Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and if you're not using it I suggest you do too because it is absolutely fantastic at what it does!

However to be **really** useful to me and my project ([and many others](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars)) I honestly believe it needs a resource/gannt view.

Not a problem one would think... until you look under the hood of jQuery FullCalendar and see that the way it generates it's views is not for javascript developer wannabes... ie me.

Having realised this is out of my league I had to go searching elsewhere looking for any calendar/scheduler that will provide a resource view.

Here are three proprietary calendars that promise this feature.

1. http://java.daypilot.org/
2. http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml
3. http://web2cal.com/ajaxeventscalendar/calendar-demo/912-premium-demo/157-scheduler-view

Unfortunately both *daypilot* and *dhtmlxscheduler* lack the clean and clear interface that FullCalendar achieves so well and *web2cal* just looks and feels unfinished and is still in Beta.

Alternatively I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could integrate a jQuery Gannt chart with jquery fullcalendar.

I have found a few projects that look promising

- http://www.maro-z.com/examples/jquery.gantt/
- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-gantt/
- http://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView

I have looked into how fullcalendar generates its views and so far have not had any success in extending this to provide a container for one of these gannt charts to 'sit within' fullcalendar and be triggered by its buttons.

This seems to be one of the more popular feature requests with many people asking for it on the official issue tracker

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

So I am left at a cross roads. I could pay for a half baked proprietary solution that has minimal to no community support or I can try and find a way of getting a resource view inside of jquery Fullcalendar by asking the people who really know jQuery.

I would happily donate the funds saved from using a proprietary solution to the developer of Fullcalendar.

The developer of FullCalendar seems to have a lot on his plate and I would like to again thank him for this truly amazing calendar.

I hope someone can share a solution with us!

Tim

Comment: You are right that FullCalendar is the best open source calendar plugin available.  FullCalendar has a very clean API, and it is absolutely possible to do what you are asking.  Since this problem has not been solved by anyone (that I know of), I would venture to guess that this is outside the scope of a stackoverflow Q&A.  I sent you an email through the contact form on your web site.  Feel free to contact me directly if you would like to discuss this further.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this can be done, but it seems like the kind of work I'd normally take on as a paid project rather than a Question/Answer format.

Comment: (The question changed since my last comment.) Perhaps there should be a collective bounty opened up for this feature? Looks like http://www.fossfactory.org supports this.

Comment: Why not just to make an offer to FullCalendar [developers](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/graphs/contributors) (e.g. directly to arshaw)?

Comment: http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/

Answer (score 19):

Just to update what has been done for this idea:

https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar

It's now a fork of fullcalendar.

Comment: I use this and it's quite nice. I wish it was part of the trunk code though. Maybe in the future it can be.

Comment: @jsop can i change width ,height of resource view? cause i am trying to do that but evets position gets disturb ? is there any way to increase height width

Comment: The link no longer works. The github for the project can be found here: https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar

Answer (score 3):

For those searching for a resource view based on v2.1.1.

[Here is a fork](https://github.com/ChurchDesk/fullcalendar) implementing it that will hopefully be merged into fullcalendar at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a pretty old question, but I was looking for something like that a few weeks ago and I couldn't find anything here. So, what I'm using is [Kendo Scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index). It has a horizontal grouping, vertical grouping, timeline and some other interesting things like bind against SignalR.

Moreover, FullCalendar [announcement](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2015/02/timeline-and-other-news.html) that it will be a [Resource/Timeline view](http://fullcalendar.io/timeline/) soon. But probably it will be released under a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

There is a https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/ which has a resource view as well. You can integrate it with full calendar. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what StackOverflow users can offer you as an answer, this is as close as you'll ever get:

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490

There is an open task and at the bottom are some work-in-progress examples of extensions to fullcalendar to achieve what you want. Please offer to contribute or clean up the code there to get it merged into the mainstream fullcalendar project.