# fullcalendar - Multiple user view

Tags: fullcalendar

How to display multiple user events in a single page in fullcalendar group by user name?

Comment: Can you please expand a little on what exactly it is you want, and probably have a read of this as well http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

The more information you supply, the better quality of answers you will get.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: You can also use the ressource view from Sean Kenny http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/08/11/fullcalendar-with-a-resource-day-view-v2-0-2/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as it is phrased now it mostly attracts link-only answers.

Comment: @sweetie have you found the solution

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in, but I'm doing it using the eventAfterRender method to modify the width and left position of the events based on an index value that is set in the feed generator.

For example: Events from user1 have a base left offset of 0px, user2 200px, user3 300px, etc and the width of the events is based on the overall width divided by the number of users. Handling overlapping events, etc was a bit of a pain, but worked out nicely in the end.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something of this sort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237974/how-to-adjust-width-and-position-of-events-in-jquery-full-calendar-in-week-view. Appreciate if you can help out with some sample code

Comment: @SomethingOn Did you have a method to share?

Comment: I no longer work at the company where I developed this and don't have the code to share...sorry :(

Comment: @SomethingOn have you found the solution? I am looking for the same

Comment: Hey guys, I no longer work for the company where I was using FullCalendar, so I don't have access to the code. If I remember correctly I basically set the width of the event and the left offset based on the number of users being shown. Eg. 2 users, the events are 50% wide and the left offsets are 0% and 50% respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what sweetie is asking for is multi-user displays on the same calendar.

Jquery-week-calendar has this feature.  http://themouette.github.com/jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar_demo_3.html  Its pretty nice.

I hope FullCalendar adds this at some point.  In the meantime, this would have to be implemented through quite a bit of customization of the event layout routine.  You'd have to assign a different css class per user and then override the layout system to display events occurring at the same time side-by-side rather than overlapping them.

Comment: I placed a feature request for this.

Comment: @gidmanma have you solved this in fullcalendar.

Comment: @YatinMistry No. It was just a side project and not part of a deliverable so I skipped it.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search there are actually a few solutions:

This page is the best you can get on the topic in Stack Overflow: [Adding a Resource View/Gannt chart to jQuery Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269117/adding-a-resource-view-gannt-chart-to-jquery-fullcalendar)

There are two fullCalendar forks that include a resource view that will do what you (and I) are looking for:

https://github.com/benbruscella/fullcalendar

https://github.com/ikelin/fullcalendar

I tried the demos and the do work.

In fact, here is a list of all the github fullCalendar forks:
http://forked.yannick.io/arshaw/fullcalendar