# How to get event resourceId when adding a new one

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add a new event manually (selecting a time range) to a specific resource, so I need the resourceId after doing it to save the event on DB. The method `select: function (start,end,allDay)` only gives me the time range but not the resourceId if I'm working with multiple resources. Any solution?

### EDIT BELOW

Ok, I'll try to explain it better.

I'm using the resource view of the calendar as you can see at [FullCalendar ResourceView](https://fullcalendar.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=4900007000&name=multiresource.png&token=zZ592xPTP2l0XxgcVQ5x9_KkXS4:1368578373088&inline=1)

When I try to select a time range ([Select Method](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/)) to add a new event, I can get the startTime and endTime, as you can see on the link provided.

But, the problem is, when I'm using the multi column view (resource view), I need the resourceId, so I will send it to server using AJAX and store it somewhere.

I have tried:

this: `select: function(start, end, resourceId){alert(resourceId)},` 
the alert is: false

and this: `select: function(start, end, event){alert(event.resourceId)},`
the alert is: undefined

Sorry about the short question!

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear 
Where is your code what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an awesome FullCalendar implementation of resourceview in another post.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269117/adding-a-resource-view-gannt-chart-to-jquery-fullcalendar)

[Implementation Link](http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/) (this is link is broken now, I will post here if I find another example on the web).

This answer the question and comes with examples.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and in fact the select method has a resource parameter in the 5th position, like this :

```
select: function(start, end, event, view, resource) {
  var resourceId = resource.id;
}
```

It did the trick for me on fullcalendar (^3.0.0-beta) with Scheduler (v1.3.3)

Comment: did it for me too. gets resourceid before rendering i think.

Comment: This works — without a doubt. The names for the parameters are for you to choose, but 'event' and 'view' parameters cannot be left out. My problem is: What if I should look for this piece of information for myself? Where in Fullcalendar documentation did you find the parameter list?

Comment: @BriceCoustillas I can’t remember.. I probably `console.log` everything I could find and checked the prototypes ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

if your event is rendered properly on the calendar, then you should just take the resource id by `select: function(start, end, event){alert(event.resource.id)}` , notice it is not resourceId.

Comment: It wasn't rendered yet, that's the problem. I need the resource.id **after** selecting a time range and **before** rendering the event.

Comment: ok, first step: `function colDate(col) { 
  return cloneDate(t.visStart);
 }` , should be like this, because as it was it counts the columns as "next days" and not as different resources. And apart from that maybe you need to make changes in function selectionManager() as well, but not sure exactly where